# Is it possible to review a review audit?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I just failed my first review audit.  After having clicked "*Looks okay*", I was confronted by the failed audit message, however the post itself that I had just reviewed was blank, leaving me unable to understand what exactly the issue with the post was.

Moving back through browser history didn't reveal the (bad) answer either. Is it possible to review failed audits?

I understand that allowing the reviewing of failed audits would make it easier to write audit system bypassing bots, but I wanted to check regardless.

Comment: Normally it is possible, but when you are given a deleted question or answer as an audit, you won't be able to see the audit afterwards unless you have the privileges to see it (i.e. you have 10K rep)

Comment: What about reviewing a review of a review audit? :)

Comment: for duplicates, it [doesn't really matter](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271329/839601) which one is asked earlier or later

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I believe the specific audit you're looking for is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5101149), but you can't review that because it's deleted. For posterity, this is the post:

[image: Review audit case]

I think what happened there was that this particular library was posted in multiple places in a short duration, that post was flagged as spam, and then it was removed. It triggered the use of this as an audit case, but you wouldn't know that if you didn't have that context.

I really would like it if [reviewers could see deleted posts that they failed an audit on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228955/allow-all-reviewers-to-see-deleted-posts-they-reviewed). This is also a pretty questionable audit, so [it would be nice to be able to dispute these](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188780/review-audits-and-i-understand-button/188790#188790).

Comment: Yes, that's the exact audit.

Comment: That request is a much better one than the [one I found](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168429/can-we-please-see-the-subject-of-failed-review-audits-even-if-the-post-has-been).

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely an edge case. I wouldn't have deleted just this one post if there weren't *many* others posted at the same time, all linking to the same site. This isn't a good post for a review.

Comment: Looks vaguely spammy anyway.  *"I tested 14,250 user agents and got 99.95 positive results with BrowserDetection and 85.56% with Browser."*  Really?  Aren't *you* an overachiever.

Comment: @Nit Damn it all to hell, I just failed this exact review myself.

Comment: @BilltheLizard - Presented without commentary: http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5168511

Comment: @Brad I'm so glad that one's preserved for posterity.

Comment: @BilltheLizard or Brad: Do you know if there's anything planned to improve this? I'm starting my second review ban after I stumbled over one of these for the second time. Granted, the most recent post was much worse than the one that tripped up Bill, but I find it really difficult to tell when a resource link should be classified as spam when looking at a post in isolation in the review queue. Particularly if flags on answers that look like much clearer cases of spam are partly disputed.