# "spam or offensive" review audit question is neither

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I just failed  [This review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6042216) and was told that it was "spam or offensive"

However, when reviewing it displayed this information, which appears to be neither of these things.

> Regular language is closed under INTERSECTION and DIFFERENCE
>   operation, nfabo is a DFA engine which support these additional
>   operations, the answer for your question would be:
>
> a1 &! a0, the engine will compile this extended regex as dfa_of(a1) &!
>   dfa_of(a0), in which &! is the DIFFERENCE operator, the result dfa
>   would match a1 but NOT match a2.

So - who reviews the reviews and is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: Follow the link?

Comment: i don't follow links... if the link is offensive - is it possible that the person who posted this accidentally pointed at the wrong place? The text of the answer is clearly not offensive.

Comment: The correct place to discuss review audits is afaik right here. The answer in the review audit is not visible to me, so here is some speculation: the user who wrote that answer may have spammed a bunch of similar answers promoting some third party tool called 'nfabo'? Did the post contain a link to this tool?

Comment: It's often seen, maybe this fit not here Use ABC for YXZ with a hidden link to a commercials like travel management companies, jewelry seller, car rentals what ever,just in hope to benefit from the google indexing of stackoverflow

Comment: yep, that's fair... but in this case, basically impossible to tell in a review-audit, which is annoying.  The answer looks like an answer.

Comment: @HugoRune it's link to a chinese(?) side, from which after translation it't is difficult to decide if it is legal, spam or hacked source. You can find things like `
febird libraries (including the automatic machine) which is no longer Open Source` in the download area.

Comment: You can find many justified complaints about the audits,, I'm not sure if the case is one of them. Just go ahead.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261032/is-it-possible-to-review-a-review-audit.

Comment: And feel free to upvote this MSE request if you agree that these types of spam posts make for useless audits: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238647/dont-use-spam-post-as-audits-in-the-low-quality-review-queue.

Comment: So thinking about it a bit more, the problem (for me) is that in the low quality review queue, I am not supposed to review whether the answer actually answers the question well... just whether the answer is well-presented. Looking at the above, it looks like the person has tried to present an answer and even given an example, and the language doesn't sound particularly spammy. Real answers look like this too - they even point at offsite locations for their tools. So... ???

Comment: unsure? then -> skip

Comment: I was not unsure

Answer (score 1):

It was flagged as spam and deleted because of that flag.

This bit:

> [nfabo](http://nfabo.cn/) is a DFA engine

is the key part. The name "nfabo" is a link.

Now, I'm not saying that it *should* have been flagged and deleted in the first place, just that having been flagged and deleted it became eligible for review and the correct response is to mark it as spam again.

Comment: Er... If there is a chance it shouldn't have been flagged and deleted in the first place, there is a chance that the correct response *isn't* to mark it as spam again, surely?

Comment: @hvd - In the context of the **review** the correct response is to flag it as *it was already flagged and deleted*. The selection of posts is automatic. Had it not been deleted then it wouldn't have been eligible for review.

Comment: If you just mean "the response that would've made you pass the audit", then sure, but if the action originally taken is incorrect, then I wouldn't call that response "correct", and I honestly did misunderstand your answer because of that.

Comment: @ChrisF - a link to software is not necessarily spammy. The answer looked like a valid answer - it looked like an answer that was not "low quality"... this was the "low quality" review queue, and I marked the answer as "not low quality". The fact that it was part of a multi-post is not visible in the low quality review queue - it the answer upon its own merits... and on its own merits, it does not look low quality.

Comment: @TarynEast - I'm not saying that all links are spam. I'm saying that in this case, because of the link the answer was flagged as spam and then deleted. Because of *that* it was presented to you in review as a spam answer.

Comment: Yes, thanks, appreciate the intent, but I already knew that. The problem is not "why was this one a fail", but "how can I prevent this from happening again when presented with the same information in future"... also "should this be removed from auditing as it is very much unclear that it is spam"